# Where do you put the image you're loading for a button in a java app?

Tags: java, image, swing, button, icons

I have a package com.supercorp.killerapp and within it is a package(com.supercorp.killerapp.views) if I'm not creating the app with the guiformbuilder:

- How do I set the icon of a button on a JInternalFrame that is in the views directory?
- In general, how do I access images in a different folder?
- Should all my images be contained in a seperate folder?

The syntax I'm using is:

```
JButton iconButton = new JButton(new ImageIcon("page_delete.png"));
```

The button isn't displaying the image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I put in the jar that contains my application, in a package called `com.example.GreatApp.resources` and then load it using:

```
getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(
               "com/example/GreatApp/resource/icon.png");`
```

**Update. Full example**

```
/**
 * Creates and returns an ImageIcon from the resource in jar.
 * @param location resource location in the jar,
 * like 'com/example/GreatApp/res/icon.png' or null if it was not found.
 */
public ImageIcon createImageIconFromResource(String location)
           throws java.io.IOException {
  java.io.InputStream input = getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(
               location);
  // or throw an ioexception here aka `file not found`
  if(input == null) return null;
  return new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(input));
}
```

Comment: Might want to connect it back to images.  Something like: `new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(stream));`

Comment: This is what I want, but I'm not sure what to do with that statement? Something like new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("com/example/GreatApp/resource/icon.png"); does that mean that I can load it even if the file that needs it is com/example/GreatApp/views/prettyform.java? Would it still be the same syntax from there as com/example/GreatApp/users/views/awesomeUserForm.java?

Comment: What class/package does getClassLoader belong to? I'm running this method but I'm not getting any kind of exception but I'm still getting no icon.

Comment: @dah `ClassName.class.getClassLoader`.

Answer (score 3):

You can put the images anywhere on the classpath. I find it most logical to put them in the root of the project in an "images" folder.

Packages map to folders when compiled & packaged so it looks like you need:

```
Image im = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage( "/com/supercorp/killerapp/views/page_delete.png" );
JButton iconButton = new JButton( new ImageIcon( im ) );
```

Comment: Does that work or do you need to do `new ImageIcon( getClass().getResource("/com/..."))`?  I don't think the `ImageIcon(String)` constructor loads from the class path.